# Convergence of sequence made from iterative scheme

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is actually a problem from an entrance test. But this problem completely defeated me.
Consider the iterative scheme
$x_n$ = $\frac{x_{n-1}} {2} + \frac{3}{x_{n-1} }$
With initial point $x_0$$\gt$0. Then the sequence ${x_n}$
1)converges only if $x_0$$\lt$$3$.
2)converges for any $x_0$.
3)converges only if $x_0\gt1$.
4)does not converge for any $x_0$.
Try :I suppose the sequence is convergent to $l$. Then taking limit $n\to \infty$ in both sides and putting $l$will give $l$ is either $0$ or $3$.Hence it is convergent either to $0$or $3$.After this stage I  have no idea. Anybody please explain me.
Thanks in advance.
Edited after the comment.

Comment: What is $l$ (ell) in "convergent to $l$"?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I suppose $l$is the limit of the sequence.

Comment: should there be an $x_{n+1}$ in the iteration?

Comment: @robjohn. I suppose that the two $x_n-1$ stand for $x_{n-1}$

Comment: Is it $x_n-1$ or $x_{n-1}$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You are right. I am sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After this stage I have no idea.

Depending on the sequence:

1. Show that $x_n$ is monotonically increasing (or decreasing), starting at some $$n>n_0$.
2. Show that $x_{n-1}-x_n\to 0$
3. Show that $x_n-\ell\to 0$ where $\ell$ is the potential limes.
4. Find a sequence $a_n$ and $a_n\to0$ such that $|x_n-\ell| \leqslant |a_n|$ as $n\to\infty$, or perhaps $|x_{n+1}-x_n| \leqslant |a_n|$.

Which of them to use depends on the sequence, for example trying to show that the sequence is monotonically increasing makes only sense when you have strong indication that this is actually the case.

To find out if any of these applies is part of the homework assignment.

Likewise, if you have indication that the series does not converge: try to find a subsequence $\{y_n\}\subset\{x_n\}$ such that:

1. $|y_n-\ell| >\varepsilon>0$ for all $y_n$ and where $\varepsilon$ does not depend on $n$.
2. $|y_{n+1}-y_n| >\varepsilon>0$ for all $y_n$ and where $\varepsilon$ does not depend on $n$.

Again, do not act blindly.  Before trying to show something, get an impression of the sequence's behavior and what approach might be successful.

Comment: How can you answer a question that has a wrong statement ?

Comment: I did not assume anything w.r.t. convergence or non-convergence (one of which *will* hold true).  As I wrote: *"do not act blindly. Before trying to show something, get an impression of the sequence's behavior*"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the problem is $$x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}}{2} + \frac{3}{x_{n-1}}$$ **if** the limit $L$ exits, it is the solution of
$$L=\frac L 2+\frac 3 L \implies L^2=6\implies L=\pm \sqrt 6\implies L=\sqrt{6} \,\,\text{sgn}(x_0)$$

Just for your curiosity, there is a closed form of $x_n$.